# Iphone storyboard application with game in webview

Tags: iphone, html

I made a HTML5 game for web browsers. Some of the players asked me if I could make it available as an App. Now I have a developer key, but just a VERY basic knowledge of Xcode / objective-c and I dont actually own an Apple computer. (But I can run Leopard/Xcode in VMWare).

1. Is it **very** bad practice to make a storyboard application that basically consists out of a splashscreen and a webview that loads my html game page with some added js/css to match the resolution?
2. Will Apple allow a game developed like this? It seems way easier to update etc...
3. Can I remove the bottom status bar from a webview using the meta tag? Or does that just work in safari, and will localstorage work?
4. Are there other, better, faster ways to port html5 to an app?

Sorry for the huge amount of questions, but I couldnt find satisfactory answers to all my questions, and I guess more people will have the same...

gr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me try to help you:

1. No, its not a "bad practice", but maybe for your app it's simple to do just a normal Single View Application. It doesn't mean that it's going to be wrong doing a storyboard, it;s just simpler.
2. Your App is only going to open a WebView with an URL, so, if you dont do anything weird, it's not going to be rejected.
3. If you are talking to the status bar, yes, it's possible to remove it easily.
4. I think that's the best way, just open a view with a webview on it. Another way is making your app call Safari with that URL, that's up to you (your app will go to the background and Safari will be called)

And an extra one: Its totally ok doing it with VMWare, I develop like that sometimes with my PC ;)

Comment: Ok man thanks! Ill accept this as an answer as soon as I get the chance... One more question: will localstorage work in webview? Its an important aspect of my game... 
Gr!

Comment: Im not pretty sure about your question, I invite you to create another question explaining that more deeply, and for sure we will find an answer!

Comment: Well I know safari supports it. Maybe the question should be: is the webview a Safari view?